# How to import a TypeScript function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I am struggling while trying to import my TypeScript function into JavaScript, I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "video/mp2t". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

This is my TypeScript code:

```
export function getStatus(): any {

    fetch('https://authserver.mojang.com/', {
       method: 'GET'
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.status);
        return response.json();
    });

    return null;
}
```

And this is my JavaScript code:

```js
import { getStatus } from "../ts/Status.ts";

let root = document.documentElement;

function setOnline() {
    root.style.setProperty('--status-color', '#47ff75')
}

function setWarning() {
    root.style.setProperty('--status-color', '#ffb247')
}

function setOffline() {
    root.style.setProperty('--status-color', '#eb3838')
}

document.onload(() => {
    console.log(getStatus());
});
```

Thank you a lot for helping!
Greetings, Leander :)

Comment: You should be importing a `.js` file.

Comment: What happens if you remove `: any ` at the end of your function declaration before importing, and saving that file with a `.js` extension?

Comment: you don't need `.ts` extensions at import statement

Comment: It works when I change my file extension to ``.js``, thank you guys!

Sadly it does not print anything into the console, could any1 help me fixing this?

Comment: "*trying to import my TypeScript function*" - no, you're not, as "*the server responded with a MIME type of "video/mp2t"*". That's not a TypeScript module at all. Fix your server to either serve the correct file or do proper file extension detection.